# Discord.py ... trying to find the users CURRENT status.. not status on change or thru discord.Member

Tags: python, discord

Unless there is a way to do it through discord.Member with what im currently doing?

current code..

````
@tasks.loop(seconds = 5) # repeat after every 60 seconds
async def checkAFK():
    global rTotalPlayers
    global cTotalPlayers

    with open('playerPop.json') as f:
        playerPop = json.load(f)

    msgChannel = await client.fetch_channel(variables['pickup'])
    for i in list(cTotalPlayers):
        cTotalPlayers[i] = cTotalPlayers[i] - 1
        if(cTotalPlayers[i] < 0):
            member = await client.fetch_user(i)
            #print(member.activities)
            print(i)
            del rTotalPlayers[playerPop[str(i)][0]]
            del cTotalPlayers[i]
            await msgChannel.send("<@" + str(i) + "> has been removed from the pickup due to being AFK.")
            print(cTotalPlayers)
            PopulateTable()
            await msgChannel.send("```" + msg + "```")
    print(cTotalPlayers)
````

What im trying to do is loop through a dictionary of players and after 60 seconds.. (in this case 5 just for testing purposes) itll subtract one.. what i wanna do is when it gets to 0.. i want it to check whether or not they have a green or moon by their name.. if moon and less than 0, itll remove them from a "pickup game".  I am trying to find this currently thru await client.fetch_user and the commented line is where im checking outputs.. anyone know how to do it via the approach im already taking?  Thanks

---

Above is fixed..  Next problem is getting the status to show correctly.. always showing offline.. code below.. dev portal stuff: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mL1R.jpg

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
#intents = discord.Intents(members = True, presences = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ["!", "+", "-"], case_insensitive=True, intents= intents)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get their status by using [`Member.status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.status)

This returns a [Status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Status) object where the property returns a True or False value.

```py
status = user.status
if status.online or status.idle:
    pass # Do something here
```

Comment: ok so this may be more of a indictment on my skill level.. but cant i only access discord.Member with a parameter? im doing this without specifying a user in the parameter.  What I have is their ID.

I guess if so, I could create a whole nother function and run each user through that

Comment: @MarkSouza You can fetch the _member_. That will return the member object of the person.

Comment: ya, thats the part im trying to figure out... i just simply do not know how to do it.. but ill keep plugging away

Comment: @MarkSouza I assume that the channel you got from `variables["pickup"]` is the same guild as the people that are playing?

Comment: [CODE]
guild = await client.fetch_guild(796815848219476019)
            user = guild.get_member(118900492607684614)
            print(guild.get_member(118900492607684614))
[/code]
this is what ive progressed to so far.. returning None

Comment: @MarkSouza Try [`Guild.fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member)

Comment: ok will do.. sorry for the lack of formatting ont hat last comment lol..

Comment: cool ya, that did it.. its saying im offline when im online (on my desktop PC.. i tried desktop_status too tho..) but ill figure that one out.. thanks!

Comment: @MarkSouza No problem! You can't format multiline code blocks on comments (see the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Also, make sure that you're online instead of invisible. You may have to mess with the object a bit.

Comment: ya im green... im reading up on intents now.. but from what i see I have everything set up.. its just flat out not accurately picking up that im online.. im sure im missing something

Comment: @MarkSouza All you need is the members Intent. Make sure that the bot has them enabled and the developer page does too.

Comment: ya i got them on there, just isnt showing up accurately. odd stuff

Comment: i went ahead and added the code at the bottom of the original post with the code i got for intents.. and uploaded the developer portal stuff here https://imgur.com/a/EA3deJT ... not sure if im missing anything else

Comment: @MarkSouza Any errors popping up in the console? Your intents do work

Comment: Nah just outputs the user im testing (myself) as offline when im online